# Bluetooth headset changing pairing mode into "media audio" only

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-audio, headset, bluetooth-pairing

I've got a Plantronics bluetooth headset which when I pair to my phone (AT&T GS3 4.0.4) works very well at first, with the headset appearing as "Connected to phone and media audio." In this mode I can e.g. listen to music and automatically transition to talking on incoming/outgoing calls.

However, recently the pairing changes, within seconds after ending a phone call, to just "Connected to media audio." In this mode I can still listen to music but not talk on the phone via the headset... In order to return to the "phone and media audio" mode, I have to disconnect and then reconnect the headset.

This is extremely annoying. Any ideas what may have started causing this and for any remedies?

Comment: I have the same issue with my Plantronics, however in my case I can't seem to get the media audio back.